# How hosting Asp.Net vNext application hosting on Kestrel, helios, WebListener and in separate Console process differs?

Tags: c#, owin, asp.net-core, katana

Asp.Net vNext being Host agnostic, applications can be hosted on many platforms in compliance with OWIN standards. And as per the discussions i hear from the developers around, typical vNext application can be hosted on Helios, Kestrel, using webListener and in separate console application process.

My intention of asking this question is, If i have to explain difference between all these to current Asp.Net developer, how will i explain it? What are the technicalities behind?

Answer (score 6):

There's nothing to explain.  You as a developer and your operations team that will support your web application can use whatever web server works best for your scenario.

Use Kestrel when you want to run on a Mac or *Nix box

Use Helios to give you the robust IIS capabilities you always had in ASP.NET

Use WebListener if you are attempting to deliver something like an Internet of Things device.

Choice is a good thing, and ASP.NET is now full of choices so that you can use it wherever and however you need it.

Comment: Why is there a need for something like kestral anyway ? Isnt weblistener (httplistener )  already a scalable webserver ?

Comment: WebListener is not a scalable web server and is intended for development purposes only.  Kestrel is a simple web server appropriate for use on non-windows (and windows) machines

Comment: Kestrel seems to be intended to offer an experience akin to node, where the programming model is less oriented towards threading and more towards a single threaded model and non-blocking IO.

Comment: @linkerro - You are more right than you know... All of ASP.NET 5 is oriented towards a node-like programming model.  We don't want you to have to think too much about threading, just tell the framework when async is allowed with async keywords.  IIS and the webListener function similarly

Comment: @JeffFritz still, it's a shame that this isn't printed in big letters atop the home page. Most people I've talked that haven't stuck their nose out of the MS ecosystem haven't picked up on the new direction.